# Styling text on TabLayout

Tags: android, android-design-library

I'm trying to style the new `TabLayout` from android design library.

```
<style name="NavigationTab" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/background_tab</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/NavigationTabTextAppeareance</item>
</style>
```

And the text is defined right here

```
<style name="NavigationTabTextAppeareance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
      <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_light</item>
      <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

But the selected tab is always black, how can I change it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

set tabSelectedTextColor in NavigationTab like this:

```
<style name="NavigationTab" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/background_tab</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/primary_light</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/NavigationTabTextAppeareance</item>
</style>

<style name="NavigationTabTextAppeareance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
      <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_light</item>
      <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 7):

If you just have to give different text color then there is direct option by using **app:tabTextColor for unselected** and  **app:tabSelectedTextColor for selected tab text** like in example .

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabTextColor="#607D8B"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#FFFFFF"/>
```