# Making TabLayout text bold

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I'm using the TabLayout from the Android Design Support library and want to style its text (title). Specifically making it bold. How to achieve that in **XML** only?

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/accent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp" />
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

First this must be added to the styles.xml:

```
<style name="TabLayoutTextStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Even if you don't want to alter the text size, you **must** include it in the styles otherwise nothing will be shown.

Then the style must be applied to the `TabLayout` using `app:tabTextAppearance` not the `style` attribute!

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/accent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp" 
app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayoutTextStyle" />
```

To enable the allcaps you may add the following to the `TabLayoutTextStyle`:

```
<item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
```

Comment: it crashed, worked when I also declared textColor in style.

Answer (score 4):

1. One option is to add In styles.xml

   ```
     <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
   ```

   inside "TextAppearance.Design.Tab" with same name as parent

   ```
   <style name="TextAppearance.Design.Tab" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
     <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
     <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
     <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorSecondary</item>
     <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
     <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
   </style>
   ```
2. Other option : inside your layout  direct to your  style -  lets say you call it myTabLayoutStyle

   ```
    style="@style/myTabLayoutStyle"
   ```

and inside that style redirect again  to other style just for  text appearance :

```
      <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/myTabTextStyle</item>
```

like that:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    style="@style/myTabLayoutStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="600dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

inside styles.xml:

```
  <style name="myTabLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabMaxWidth">@dimen/tab_max_width</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">4dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingStart">3dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingEnd">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/myTabTextStyle</item>
  </style>

   <style name="myTabTextStyle">
       <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
       <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
       <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorSecondary</item>
       <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
       <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
  </style>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the following styles

```
<style name="TabLayoutTextStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Now you can just use it like:

Then the style must be applied to the TabLayout using app:tabTextAppearance not the style attribute!

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
     app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
     app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/accent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayoutTextStyle" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add TabLayout Text Style in styles.xml

---

```
<style name="TabLayoutTextStyle">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

And set `TabLayoutTextStyle` as style to yor TabLayout properties.

---

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/accent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp" 
style="@style/TabLayoutTextStyle" />
```

Comment: Follow this link, It should maybe work... [Styling text on TabLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31271945/4910513)

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to do this.

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Bold"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/grey"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```